# jQuery add alt tag to images with same src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

There are many images with same URL source but the first image only that has the Alt tag, so how can I add alt to the other image with the same source?

```js
$(function(){
    var srcs = [],
        alt = '',
        title = '',
        temp;
    $("img").filter(function(){
        temp = $(this).attr("src");
        alt = $(this).attr("alt");
        title += $(this).attr("title");

        if($.inArray(temp, srcs) < 0){
            srcs.push(temp);
            srcs.push(alt);
            srcs.push(title); 
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }).attr('alt',alt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="colourDots">
   <img alt="aaa" title="axxx" src="/out/pictures/generated/product/8/300_450_100/60028.bl.jpg"/><br>
   <img src="/out/pictures/generated/product/8/300_450_100/60028.bl.jpg"/><br>
   <img  alt="bbb" title="axxx" src="/out/pictures/generated/product/8/300_450_100/60028.bl.jpg"/><br>
   <img src="/out/pictures/generated/product/8/300_450_100/60028.sw.jpg"/><br>
   <img src="/out/pictures/generated/product/8/300_450_100/60028.bl.jpg"/><br>
   <img src="/out/pictures/generated/product/8/300_450_100/60028.bl.jpg"/><br>
   <img src="/out/pictures/generated/product/8/300_450_100/60028.bl.jpg"/><br>
</div>
```

Simply I need filter images to get

All images that have same source URL.

Copy the alt tag to other images that haven't alt but have same source URL

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, is your question "how do I add `alt` attributes to images that are lacking those right now"? Because by far the better place to do that would be where you generate all these img element tags.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Simply I need filter images to get all images that have same source URL then copy the alt tag to other images that haven't alt but have same source URL

Comment: Find all images, and reduce that list to all unique `src`. Then for each unique src, get all images with that source, sub select an element with an `alt` and then set all the images (including the one you just found) to use that alt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. get all unique src attributes,
2. for each unique src attribute, get all images that use it
3. for each set, find a member with `alt` and then assing that to the entire set.

In code:

```
const uniques = [];
const imgs = $('img');

imgs.each(function () {
  let src = this.src;
  if (uniques.indexOf(src) === -1) uniques.push(src);
});

uniques.forEach(src => {
  let srcd = imgs.filter("img[src='"+src+"']");
  let alt = srcd.filter('[alt]').first().attr('alt');

  srcd.each( function() {
    $(this).attr('alt',alt);
  })
});
```

Comment: Not working. need the images have the same source get the same alt also

Comment: ... that is literally what this code does. For each known `src` string, it finds *all* images with that src, then makes sure they all end up with the same `alt` attribute, so if this doesn't work, please say what isn't working. "not working" is not useful information in order to fix things, it's just an opinion (the computer does exactly what you tell it to)

Comment: I have edited the selector variable commas then try but got uniqueSrc is not defined, did you tried it in jsfiddle?

Comment: That was a paste error that I could have fixed much earlier if you'd mentioned uniqueSrc gave an error =) Updated the text.

Comment: Update the code but not doing any effects see here http://jsfiddle.net/earngate/xkhvjjqp/

Comment: I have created new one and it's add alt  so same image src but to one only see here http://jsfiddle.net/earngate/u5n0pf7n/

Comment: well yeah obviously, that's not the code I used, because the code you have in that fiddle is nothing like what I wrote. You're rerunning X times, given X image tags in your source.

Comment: Here. http://jsfiddle.net/u5n0pf7n/18/ spells it out in more detail than was necessary, uses some lesser known jquery selection filtering, and generally does exactly what you need. And before you go "but some images don't have alt still!", I know, you didn't give any your _025.jpg images an alt text.That's on you to figure out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer also this work fine http://jsfiddle.net/earngate/u5n0pf7n/

Answer (score 0):

The first version (with comments) assigns the value of only the first instance of `alt` to all images:

```
$(function () {
    // Get value of first instance of 'alt' for images within elements of the given class
    var alt = $(".colourDots img[alt]").first().attr("alt");
    // If value of 'alt' is not null or undefined
    // (Note, use != and not !== for this test)
    if (alt != null) {
        // Iterate images within elements of class .colourDots
        $.each($(".colourDots img"), function () {
            // assign value of var alt to each image
            $(this).attr("alt", alt);
        });
    }
});
```

and the second version assigns the `alt` value of the element to subsequent images (so `alt="bbb"` in your question is picked up and assigned to subsequent images):

```
$(function () {
    // Define a holding variable
    var alt;
    // Iterate images
    $.each($(".colourDots img"), function () {
        // If element has 'alt', assign the value to var alt
        if ($(this).attr("alt") != null) {
            alt = $(this).attr("alt");
        }
        // otherwise assign the value of var alt to the image
        else {
            $(this).attr("alt", alt);
        }
    });
});
```

You can take your pick, depending on what your specific needs are.

Comment: Check my code, I think you can optimize your code by running the loop only when there is a tag with no alt tag.

Comment: Thanks, but won't your code have to iterate images anyway to find those that do not have an alt attribute in the first place?

Comment: how can we supposed to fix it?